# Should a Test Statistic Consist of a Consistent Estimator for the Parameter of Interest?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, estimators

Suppose that we want to test the following hypothesis:
$$H_0: \theta \in \Theta_0\quad vs \quad H_1: \theta\in \Theta_0^c.$$

Suppose that our test statistic is $T_n$.

**Then, should the test statistic $T_n$ consist of a consistent estimator for $\theta$?
(That is, $T_n(\hat{\theta})$)**

The test statistics we learned in the undergraduate-level statistics contain the consistent estimator for the parameter of interest, usually. However, I think, that doesn't seem to be a requirement.

If we can derive a distribution of the test statistic and construct a appropriate critical region, that is it. Is my understand correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're designing a test for people to use, you want that test to work reasonably well at a variety of sample sizes.

Consequently, *if* you have an estimator of a relevant population quantity in the test statistic - or some function of one - as would typically be the case, then you will nearly always want it to be consistent. Otherwise, generally speaking, a test based on a consistent estimator is eventually going to do better. An inconsistent estimator may be very bad in large samples -- though a consistent estimator may not be that good relative to something that makes better use of the information in the sample; that is a consistent estimator may still be very inefficient, and so a test based on one may still have poor relative test efficiency.

If you have a distributional model then in a wide variety of situations you will want to base your tests on the likelihood. For example see the Neyman-Pearson lemma. Similarly, when estimating, if you have a distributional model then again you will usually want to base your estimators on maximizing the likelihood (or ones that are asymptotically equivalent to doing so).

In such a situation, you won't necessarily *seek* to make a test statistic contain a consistent estimator of a relevant population quantity, but it generally will.

When constructing permutation and bootstrap statistics, good estimators of the quantity your hypothesis relates to are typically quite important.

For a one-off situation, you don't necessarily need a consistent estimator though. That is, if you're just designing a test statistic for *this particular sample size*, then you wouldn't need it to get better at sample sizes you don't have. (I have no good examples of this, however, and I expect that situations where there's a test statistic based on an inconsistent estimator which you'd care to use in practice are not at all common.)